# ag-grid angular 8,

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

Estimados tengo el siguiente codigo, donde debido a cierta condicion debe mostrar un icono para eliminar un registro:

```
 {headerName: 'Eliminar', field: '', width: 120, minWidth: 120, maxWidth: 150, sortable: true,
            cellRenderer: function (params) {                  
                if (params.data.n_entregado === '0')
                {                                                                               
                  return '<mat-icon _ngcontent-c57="" (click)="EliminarDotacion()" class="secondary-text s-24 mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">clear</mat-icon>';                                
                }                                   
              }              
            }

  EliminarDotacion(valor){


      console.log(valor);   //console.log("probando");
     }
```

El detalle es que no reconoce el evento (click), el metodo esta fuera del constructor, no lo agarra.
Espero sus opiniones, estoy usando ag-grid la ultima version y angular 8

Answer (score 0):

puedes probar usando @HostListener y asignandolo al bloque de html que declaras en el ts (https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener).

```
@Directive({selector: 'button[counting]'})
class CountClicks {
  numberOfClicks = 0;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn) {
    console.log('button', btn, 'number of clicks:', this.numberOfClicks++);
 }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<button counting>Increment</button>',
})
class App {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería usar un `ICellRendererComp` y ese componente *custom* que se inserta por referencia contendría al icono (con su lógica para mostrarlo) y actuaría como esperas.